# increase numbering for \visible in beamer

Tags: beamer

When I prepare for my beamer slides.  Often I find myself having add/remove blocks marked by \visible, and I have to manually change the numbering.  I wonder if there is a way to tell latex to increase/subtract these numbering?

Let me try to illustrate what I have in mind, starting with a working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \visible<1->{First block}
  \visible<2->{Second block}
  \visible<3->{Third block}
  \visible<4->{Fourth block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Let's say I delete the second block and then insert a new one between the 3rd and 4th block.  Is there a way to issue a command to adjust the numbering instead of manually changing the numbers, like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \visible<1->{First block}
%
% delete the second one
%
  [hypothetic latex command that say from now on, subtract one from each \visible number]
  \visible<3->{Third block}

  [hypothetic latex command that say I will add an extra \visible block]

  \visible< something >{new block}

  \visible<4->{Fourth block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The issues is that I have quite a few of these, and I make changes all the time, so manaully editing these get tedious and error-prone.

MANY THANKS for your help!

p.s.  Let's discuss else the merit or otherwise about hiding/uncovering blocks of text in slides :-)

Comment: You can use `<+->` instead of explicit numbers. It (roughly) means "on the next slide".

Comment: You can read up about these relative overlays @Rmano mentioned in section "9.6.4 Incremental Specifications" of the beamer user guide

Comment: @Rmano would you like to answer?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz done, I was looking for a duplicate (sure there is something about it), but I didn't find one...

Comment: @Rmano Thanks! (I'm sure there are plenty of dupes, but hard to find as they are usually mixed with other stuff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the trick with

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \visible<+->{First block}
  \visible<+->{Second block}
  \visible<+->{Third block}
  \visible<+->{Fourth block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can read about it in the manual, as [pointed out by @samacarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698924/increase-numbering-for-visible-in-beamer?noredirect=1#comment1736724_698924), when it explains incremental specifications.